# Unable to click on the highlighted element by idex

Tags: java, appium-android

I am automating a test to test a mobile app, and I am having difficulty to locate this particular element to apply a click().

I have highlighted the element as per below, denoted by index no. 32

[image]

The code that I use to perform the click action is as below :

`driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout//android.widget.LinearLayout//android.widget.FrameLayout//android.widget.LinearLayout//android.widget.FrameLayout//android.widget.RelativeLayout//android.webkit.WebView//android.webkit.WebView//android.view.View[@index='32']")).click();`

but it i returning a NoSuchElementException error.

Hope to have advice on what mistake I could have possibly done.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath construction is wrong. Use below code

driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index='0']/android.webkit.WebView[@index='1']/android.webkit.WebView[@index='0']/android.view.View[@index='32']")).click();

Comment: I have tried your code, but it's still returning NoSuchElement exception. Anything I can provide to assist in your investigation ? Also, appreciate your advice on what mistake I have commit in my original code. Thanks